# How to query to filter unwanted records?

Tags: sql

If I have a table with records that match columns n_month and n_year, how can I query to exclude the record with the older date, keeping the record with the latest date?  An example table looks like:

```
n_month n_year      factor      d_expire
===========================================
10      2019        63.2        16-FEB-2018
11      2019        77.6        15-FEB-2018       <-- unwanted
11      2019        82.3        16-FEB-2018
12      2019        58.0        16-FEB-2018
```

and I want to end up with:

```
n_month n_year      factor      d_expire
===========================================
10      2019        63.2        16-FEB-2018
11      2019        82.3        16-FEB-2018
12      2019        58.0        16-FEB-2018
```

The actual table I'm working with is more complex, and I eventually experimented until I had what I think is a very complex query that involves multiple UNION and JOIN elements to end up with the result I want, but I'm hoping that I can replace my initial (large and ugly) solution with a simpler one.  SQL is not my strong suit so I'm hoping someone can see the simplest solution to this query.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your existing query?

Comment: It's a common `Top-N Per Group` task. Just search for this string.

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: It's on Oracle.  I'll lookup Top-N Per Group task and see if that helps.  If not I'll post my current ugly query.  Thanks.

Comment: Looks like this could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531759/top-n-per-group-query-in-vertica   Thanks PM 77-1 for the pointer to the Top-N Per Group task.  It led me to the duplicate post.  I'll  try the solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rank the rows sorted by date and get rid of the ones with a 1, that would be the ones with older date:

```
SELECT innerTable.n_month, innerTable.n_year, innerTable.factor, innerTable.d_expire
FROM (
    SELECT YourTable.n_month, YourTable.n_year, YourTable.factor, 
    YourTable.d_expire, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YourTable.d_expire) AS 
    Numbering
    FROM YourTable
) AS innerTable
WHERE innerTable.Numbering > 1
```

Edit: if you could have more than one row with the oldest date, but you just one to get rid of one of them, then you change RANK for ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT innerTable.n_month, innerTable.n_year, innerTable.factor, innerTable.d_expire
FROM (
    SELECT YourTable.n_month, YourTable.n_year, YourTable.factor, 
    YourTable.d_expire, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY YourTable.d_expire) AS 
    Numbering
    FROM YourTable
) AS innerTable
WHERE innerTable.Numbering > 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like the solution I found at an older post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531759/top-n-per-group-query-in-vertica  and it works.  Much cleaner than my original query.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can just put some date calculations in your where condition

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE('16.2.2018', '%d.%c.%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(d_expire, '%d-%b-%Y')) <= 0
```

should handle your custom format "DAY-MONTHNAME-YEAR" (see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)
DATEDIFF calculates the differnce between your d_expire date and a given date (fixed from a string, or CURDATE() for current date etc.)